# Javascript "Refference error"

Tags: javascript

I have this file `upload.js` which contains this:

```
var app = app | {};


(function(o){

    "use strict";

    //Private methods

    var ajax, getFormData, setProgress;

    ajax = function(data){
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(), uploaded;

        xmlhttp.open('post', o.options.processor);
        xmlhttp.send(data);
    };

    getFormData = function(source){

    };

    setProgress = function(value){

    };

    o.uploader = function(options){
        o.options = options;

        if(o.options.files !== undefined){
            ajax({});
        }
    }

})(app);
```

and I have this in my `upload.php`:

```
<script type="javascript/text" src="<? echo APP_ROOT; ?>public/js/upload.js"></script>

    <script>
            var pathname = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/";

            document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();

                var f = document.getElementById('file'),
                    pb = document.getElementById('pb'),
                    pt = document.getElementById('pt');

                    app.uploader({
                        files: f,
                        progressBar: pb,
                        progressText: pt,
                        processor: pathname,

                        finished: function(data){
                            console.log(data);
                        },

                        error: function(){
                            console.log('Not working!');
                        }

                    });
            });

    </script>
```

and every time I click on the `submit` button I get this javascript error in my console `ReferenceError: app is not defined` what is wrong with it ? Please help.

Comment: You're using `|` instead of `||`.

Comment: | does not do what you think it does

Comment: Not sure that would fix it though... `app | {}` should evaluate to `0`, not `undefined`. I don't think that the script is being loaded in at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the Pipe sign to logical OR operator sign instead of using a Bitwise OR operator. (as per suggestion/correction by [pid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3227403/pid))

```
var app = app || {};
```

It would fix it.

Comment: Actually, `|` and `||` are both OR operators. There is no pipe operator in JS. It's not Linux. The `|` performs a bitwise OR and the `||` performs a logical OR and they are both called "OR" :)

Comment: Thanks alot for that information brother! :) I never knew that part...Thanks alot .. @pid

Comment: thank @Afzaal Ahmad Zeeshan, it actually worked, I think I missed that one :)

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, the `||` works like coalesce.

If the first term (term before `||`) is falsy, the assignment is given to the second term (term after `||`).

The `|` is bitwise `or` in js.

`||` is also short circuit `or` operator as it is in many other languages.